# laravel 5.2: Command "optimize" is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.2.

When I run composer install and composer update command, it show error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException] Command "optimize" is not defined.
```

Please let me know how to solved this problem.

Comment: Post your composer.json file

Answer (score 16):

This artisan command is deprecated.  Simply remove it from your composer.json file.

Answer (score 6):

```
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate",
            "php artisan jwt:secret -f"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
```

remove `php artisan optimize` from `post-install-cmd` array and also from `post-update-cmd`
than it will look like this.

```
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate",
            "php artisan jwt:secret -f"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        ]
    },
```

working perfectly fine without any warning.

Answer (score 4):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade says:

> The previously deprecated `optimize` Artisan command has been removed.
>   With recent improvements to PHP itself including the OPcache, the
>   `optimize` command no longer provides any relevant performance benefit.
>   Therefore, you may remove  `php artisan optimize` from the `scripts`
>   within your `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the after install or upgrade laravel following commands will be executed through composer.json file. Since 5.2 onwards optimize command has been depreciated. Please remove it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add of other accepted answer posted :

I face this error while migrating project from laravel5.2 to laravel5.6

Made following change in the composer.json

- Ensure "post-create-project-cmd" of "Scripts" doesn't have    "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
          "php artisan optimize" line
- Ensure "post-update-cmd" of "Scripts" doesn't have
  "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
          "php artisan optimize" line

** Still project didn't run**

Log file shows "Please provide a valid cache path" error. Run following command from project root and it worked.

```
 mkdir -p storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache}
```